# Req.params and req.user missing after hitting stripe checkout flow

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate Stripe subscriptions billing in my app with a tiered pricing model and based on my understanding, I need to do two things:

1. Allow my new users to also create a stripe customer account (via the integration)
2. Monitor Stripe webhook 'events' to provision access while customer subscription payments are active

My userflow is as follows:

- create profile in my app (saved to database) -> redirected to stripe checkout portal for billing info (saved to stripe database) -> *attempt* to save stripe customerId to my database so I can monitor subscription status

However, I can't figure out how to save the customerId info in my app because `req.user` and `req.params` are empty as the users are sent *back* to my app from the stripe billing portal

**Controller function**

```
module.exports.stripeWebhook = async (req, res) => {
    let data;
    const webhookSecret = stripeWebhookSecret;
         if (webhookSecret) {
      let event;
      let signature = req.headers["stripe-signature"];

      try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
          req.body,
          signature,
          webhookSecret
        );
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`);
        return res.sendStatus(400);
      }
      data = event.data;
      eventType = event.type;
    } else {
      // retrieve the event data directly from the request body.
      data = req.body.data;
      eventType = req.body.type;
    }

    switch (eventType) {
        case 'payment_intent.succeeded': {
          console.log('PaymentIntent was successful!');
          break;
      }
    case 'checkout.session.completed':
          // Payment is successful and the subscription is created.
          // You should provision the subscription and save the customer ID to your database.
          console.log(data.object.customer);  <- works
          const user = await User.findById(req.user.id); <- comes back empty so my next two lines of code don't work
          user.stripeId.push(data.object.customer);
          await user.save();
      break;
        default:
      }
      res.sendStatus(200);
  };
```

**App.js**

```
app.use(bodyParser.raw({type: "application/json"}));
app.use(express.json({ limit: '1mb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

I included the app.js code because the `bodyparser.raw` has an impact on how the body comes through in my controller function.

I was counting on the req.user or req.params to find the user in my database but it's not working. How do I save the customerId to my database like the stripe comments suggest?

Comment: If they're sending it back to your app, wouldn't it be in req.body? Are they sending it to some http endpoint on your app?

Comment: `checkout.session.completed` is a webhook event request sent by Stripe and there's no `req.user` field and it doesn't include params. If you wish to save user id with Stripe, you can set it in [metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata) and it can be found in the event itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create Stripe customer account before creating checkout session for the customer.

1. Check if customer already have `stripe_customer` account (Stripe customer account). If yes, use that one. If not, create one for him and save it in database.
2. Set `stripe_customer` for the checkout session, so customer will be automatically authenticated in the Stripe checkout
3. You can optionally put user's `_id` in the metadata of the Stripe checkout session, so you access that data later in the webhook.

**Note:** You should create one `stripe_customer` account for each currency. So one user can have multiple `stripe_customer` accounts, one for each currency.

```js
router.post('/create-checkout-session', authenticate.verifyUser, async (req, res) => {
    const { currency } = req.body;

    ...

    // If user does not have stripe customer for order currency, create a new one.
    if (!(req.user.stripe_customer && req.user.stripe_customer[currency])) {
      const new_stripe_customer = await stripe.customers.create({
        email: req.user.email,
        metadata: {
          user_id: req.user._id.toString(),
        },
      });

      let update = {};
      update[`stripe_customer.${currency}`] = new_stripe_customer.id;
      await Users.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, update);

      if (!req.user.stripe_customer) {
        req.user.stripe_customer = {};
        req.user.stripe_customer[currency] = new_stripe_customer.id;
      } else {
        req.user.stripe_customer[currency] = new_stripe_customer.id;
      }
    }

    ...

    // Set `stripe_customer` for checkout session.
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      customer: req.user.stripe_customer[currency],
      ...
    });
 
    ...

}
```

Comment: Hi @NeNaD - thanks for the response (marked the answer complete). This works great but it's creating customers during the checkout but they don't have first/last names in stripe. Any idea how I could get the webhook to add first & last name to the stripe customer in the webhook?

Comment: I should add that I don't get the users name anywhere in my signup flow -- it's something that the stripe checkout form captured.